# Regex extracting a part of log file two lines above the keyword

Tags: python, regex, file, parsing, logging

I'm trying to write a Python script to assist with parsing log file to search for *timestamps* based on a *unique ID*. File is very long, and tricks I've tried would select **everything** above key-word line. Ideally I'd like to have a keyword (ID) and a matching regex appended to it for maximum clarity; this I will try to achieve using Python. But could I ask if somebody could help me improve on regex expression for the following code.
Regex attempt, that select **everything** above the *_id*:

```
((.*\n){2}).*8355371640847
```

And the code in question:

```
 ...
    ...
    ..
    ..
    _ommited everythig: *ignore everything beyond*
    createTime: 2020-06-03T16:01:35.812Z --only this line to be selected
    employee:
      _id: 835537164084782 -- ID that is used as a reference to return 'createTime' two lines above
      code: null
      ...
      ...
      ...
```

Comment: Well, your pattern actually should match and capture the two lines into Group 1. See `(?m)^((?:.*\n){2}).*8355371640847` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Oe0egL/1), which is basically the same.

Comment: Not a regex soluation per se, but you could read the log file through a 3-element max long [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) and easily reach back three lines to fetch previously read data when a match is found.

Comment: You said you are looking for the timestamp above the given id. This will give you the timestamp only. `x = re.findall(r'createTime: (.*?) .*835537164084782', str, flags=re.DOTALL)`

Answer (score 0):

try this
(([^\n]*\n[^\n]*\n)).*8355371640847

Comment: I'm sorry, but it does seem to find any matches using the regex101.com

Answer (score 0):

Good Morning,
I do not understand for that I definitely tried it multiple times. But the code:

```
((.*\n){2}).*8355371640847
```

actualy does the job; it does select **only** the line which is two lines above the search string. Yesterday same string selected *everything*, but it maybe have had to do something how I copy/pasted the DB dump.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are trying to get this

```
a = """ _ommited everythig: *ignore everything beyond*
    createTime: 2020-06-03T16:01:35.812Z --only this line to be selected
    employee:
      _id: 835537164084782 -- ID that is used as a reference to return 'createTime' two lines above
      code: null """
x = re.compile('([^\n]*\n[^\n]*\n)[^\n]*8355371640847')
print (x.findall(a))
x = re.compile('([^\n]*\n)[^\n]*\n[^\n]*8355371640847')
print (x.findall(a))
```

output is:
['    createTime: 2020-06-03T16:01:35.812Z --only this line to be selected\n    employee:\n']
['    createTime: 2020-06-03T16:01:35.812Z --only this line to be selected\n']